# What is a self-intersection of an algebraic curve?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-curves

This question is probably naive, but I was wondering: what exactly is a self-intersection in the graph of a polynomial's zero set?

For some parametric curve described by $x(t),y(t)$, a self-intersection is plainly the point $(x,y)$ for which, for some $w\neq t$, $x(w)=x(t)=x$ and $y(w)=y(t)=y$, with some trivial assumptions about the curve itself.

Yet for curves that are not parametrized, I have a hard time pinning down exactly what goes on at a point where the graph intersects itself. The point itself is the same point here, there, and everywhere else; no funny $w$ and $t$ business.

**My question:** Is there a definition of a self-intersection of the zero set of a polynomial, and what is remarkable about these points compared to others? Also, are there different kinds of intersection points? Because clearly, what we see here:

[image]

Is not the same as what we see here:

[image]

Even though both graphs are the zero sets of one polynomial.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with your second graph, they are two different curves, given two curves an intersection point is a point on both. $x^2-y^2=0$ is not one curve, it is two curves, $x+y=0$ and $x-y=0$. What I'm showing in my answer is that a self-intersection is when we have only one curve which becomes two curves in the local completion (when the base field is $\Bbb{R}$ then $y^2-x^2(x+1)=0$ becomes the two curves $y=x(1+x)^{1/2},y=-x(1+x)^{1/2}$ at the cost of introducing the analytic function $(1+x)^{1/2}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cubic $C:y^2=x^2(x+1)$ has a self-intersection at $(0,0)$.

[image]

To see it algebraically let $k=\Bbb{R}$ or any field of characteristic not $2$, the ring of polynomials functions $C\to k$ is $$k[C]=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))$$ the subring regular at $(0,0)$ of the field of rational functions is $$k[C]_{(x-0,y-0)} = \{ \frac{u}{v},u,v\in K[C],v(0,0)\ne 0\}$$
$m=(x-0,y-0)$ is its only maximal ideal and its $m$-adic completion is 
$$\varprojlim_{n\to\infty} k[C]_{(x-0,y-0)}/m^n=k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))$$ $$=k[[x,y]]/((y-x(1+x)^{1/2})(y+x(1+x)^{1/2}))$$ $$\cong k[[x,y]]/(y-x(x+1)^{1/2}))\times k[[x,y]]/(y+x(1+x)^{1/2}))$$
where $$(1+x)^{1/2}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty {1/2\choose l} x^l \in k[[x]]$$
That the completion at $(0,0)$ is the product of two integral domains indicates a self-intersection of two smooth pieces of curves.

> When $k\subset\Bbb{C}$ the formal series gives an analytic parametrization of the two pieces of curves passing through $(0,0)$ : $$y=x\sum_{l=0}^\infty {1/2\choose l} x^l , \qquad y=-x\sum_{l=0}^\infty {1/2\choose l} x^l $$

Then search about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory

Comment: (Not the downvote) while I understand a good bit of your answer, I'm looking for something with a little less firepower. Also, I am still looking for an explanation as to whether the two intersections shown in my graphs are in any way different from each other.